# Django order_by two fields, with first field nulls last

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

I want to sort a queryset by two fields, let's say timestamp and name.
I will have a number of records where the timestamp is null, but all records will have a name.
I want all of the records that have a timestamp to come first, sorted by timestamp, followed by all the records with null timestamps, but with a secondary sort by name.

Example sorted results:

```
Timestamp   Name
---------   ----------
10:00       John
10:00       Kevin
10:00       Xavier
11:00       Arnold
12:00       Steve
(null)      Abe
(null)      Ben
(null)      Catherine
(null)      Zeke
```

I know that I can put nulls last when sorting by a single field, like this:

Person.objects.order_by(F('timestamp').asc(nulls_last=True))

I'm just not sure how to get the secondary sort field (name) in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

Person.objects.order_by(F('timestamp').asc(nulls_last=True), 'name')

Comment: Just to add to this solution. The import for the `F` class is `from django.db.models import F`